# Borrowing in Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I am fairly new to Rust. Therefore I don't have such a deep understanding of the borrow checker etc. I already did a compiler in C++ and so I tried to do the same thing in Rust as it seemed to be a nice opportunity to learn it.

I already finished my lexer and it workes pretty great and I am also pretty happy with Rust in gernal. But the borrow checker and the lifetimes trip me up sometimes. As I wanted to create my Parser, I fell into a problem that frustrates me quite some bit. To give a simplified structure of my implementation I have this following code:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum TokenKind {
    Test,
}

struct Token<'a> {
    source: &'a str,
    kind: TokenKind,
}

struct Parser<'a> {
    tokens: &'a [Token<'a>],
    position: usize,
}

impl<'a> Parser<'a> {
    fn matches(&mut self, kinds: &[TokenKind]) -> Option<&Token> { // rustc: let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1` 
        let current = match self.current() { // rustc: `self.position` is borrowed here 
            Some(current) if kinds.contains(&current.kind) => current,
            _ => return None,
        };

        self.position += 1; // rustc: cannot assign to `self.position` because it is borrowed `self.position` is assigned to here but it was already borrowed 
        Some(current) // rustc: returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1` 
    }

    fn current(&self) -> Option<&Token> {
        self.tokens.get(self.position)
    }
}
```

Now my question is how to fix this code? Why is "self.position" already been borrowed by the "self.current" method? Maybe it's a fundamental problem that I am not certain of.

Even though I read the documentation of the borrow checking and lifetime I am not quite sure how to fix this problem. So I would be glad for some help even if it's just a resource that tackles this exact problem.

Comment: You may be bumping up against an [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) problem.

Comment: My recommendation for beginners: don't bother with lifetimes. Save it for later. Only used owned types in structs (that is, replace `&str` with `String` or `Box<str>` if you are pedantic and don't want the extra redundant word (like me), and `&[Token]` with `Vec<Token>`). Yes, this will require some cloning and thus won't squeeze the 5% bits of performance, but it will make you're life a whole lot easier (and you probably don't need those percents anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now my question is how to fix this code? Why is "self.position" already been borrowed by the "self.current" method? Maybe it's a fundamental problem that I am not certain of.

While rust can split borrows *intra*procedurally, it can't do so *inter*procedurally.

`current` is an `&Token`, but because it's the result of calling `Parser::current` it's linked to a borrow of *the entirety of self*. So as long as that is outstanding, you can not update any member of `self`.

The solution is to just inline `current`, this way the split borrows are intraprocedural and the compiler can understand what happens.

An alternative is to remove `position` and make `tokens` a (peekable) iterator instead. Or make it a non-peekable iterator but have `match` work on a "current token" which is the last token obtained from the iterator (that's basically the same result).

Comment: Reworking this code to follow the iterator pattern is probably a great idea. Implementing `next()` is generally super easy.

Comment: So, first of all thanks for the reply and the suggestions you made. I took the path of using an Iterator and it works pretty well now.